# WhatsApp Web does not work on Firefox

Tags: firefox, windows, whatsapp

`WhatsApp Web` does not work with `Firefox 47.0.1` on Windows 7 64-bit OS. I have tried making it work after disabling the add-ons and restarting Firefox in safe mode, yet this did not resolve the issue either. I am not even presented the QR code as you can see in the following screenshot this is what I get when I go to [WhatsApp Web](https://web.whatsapp.com/). However, on my office desktop PC which also runs the same Windows OS and the same Firefox version, this page loads correctly. What might be the problem?

[image]

Comment: When I use the option `Refresh Firefox` it works, yet this also deletes all my preferences and add-ons. I also tried with safe mode but it did not work. I want to find the plug-in or setting responsible for this. The address bar says something suggestive: `https://web.whatsapp.com/browsers.html?missing=localstorage,sessionstorage`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay I got the problem resolved without messing with add-ons, plug-ins, history, bookmarks and sync features by just displaying `Troubleshooting Information` from the menu to the right of the Firefox. Then I opened the profile folder from there and deleted the `prefs.js` file to have it refreshed. When I launched the browser again all my settings were gone, but I was able to log into WhatsApp Web.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using Waterfox 56.2.7.1 (64-bit) and all of the sudden, one morning, I started to receive the message below when I tried to access web.whatsapp.com:

> WhatsApp works with Mozilla Firefox 30+ To use WhatsApp, update
>   Firefox or use Google Chrome, Safari, Microsoft Edge or Opera.

In `about:config` `privacy.resistFingerprinting` was false. I change it to true and now I can access web.whatsapp.com, after pressing <kbd>LEFT CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

Solved here. type **about:config** in the address bar. Locate the option **dom.storage.enabled** and set it to **True**

Answer (score 1):

Try go Help>Troubleshooting information and click on the safe mode restart firefox without add-on. After login whatsapp on safe mode just restart your firefox back with add-on and it should be logged in.

Answer (score 1):

I use Waterfox, a fork of FIrefox. Current version is 56.2.10. I followed `Anderson_`'s answer, Just pressing `CTRL + F5` (regardless of which `CTRL` key) works for me every time I do it,

According to [this site](https://tinkertry.com/for-any-browser-running-on-windows-ctrl-f5-forces-reload-from-network-not-cache)¹, `CTRL + F5` makes a browser reload the page from network rather than from cache.

If Waterfox simply goes to WhatsApp Web or a "normal" reload command is issued, `Whatsapp works with Mozilla FIrefix 30+` page pops back up. It also obviously happpens when Waterfox just launches and loads WhatsApp Web. In general, browsers load/reload pages from cache, so forcing a network reload with `CTRL + F5` seems to reliably bypasse cache, therefore, bypassing the issue.

1. https://tinkertry.com/for-any-browser-running-on-windows-ctrl-f5-forces-reload-from-network-not-cache

Answer (score 0):

For me, switching `privacy.resistFingerprinting` back to `false` in `about:config` solved the issue.

Comment: Why? ..........